# How to get the first object value from return from async function?

Tags: node.js

In order for me to process an 3DS Auth in nodejs i need to have a modal and handle the next_action property from the payment gateway, the question is how to get a specific value from an object returned by an async function?

**Example**

```
    const nextAction = async () => {

        const result = await payment.paymentIntents.retrieve(paymentIntentId);
        console.log(result);

        return await payment.paymentIntents.retrieve(paymentIntentId)
        .then(nextAction => {
            return{nextAction.data.attributes.next_action.redirect.url, nextAction.data.attributes.next_action.redirect.return_url};
        }).catch(err => {
            return err;
        });
    }
```

as you can see i need the **redirect.url** and **redirect.return_url** to be used separately on another async function, how do i get those separately? most of the time i use:

```
var next = await nextAction();
```

to get the value of nextAction async function.

Comment: You need to give your properties known property names when returning that object as in `{x: 1, y: 2}`.  Then, you can refer to the desired property name in the return value as `next.x`..

Comment: @jfriend00 alright i think i just found my savior, thanks a lot.